# Piwik Analytics with GitLab CE

Tags: gitlab, matomo

I've looked at the configuration options for GitLab CE regarding analytics and found that if I configured the following line in */etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb*, I would be able to track my GitLab CE usage:

```
gitlab_rails['extra_piwik_url'] = 'my.piwik.hostname'
gitlab_rails['extra_piwik_site_id'] = '2'
```

After doing a *gitlab-ce reconfigure*, I can see in the HTML source of the pages the following tracking code:

```
<script>
  var _paq = _paq || [];
  _paq.push(["trackPageView"]);
  _paq.push(["enableLinkTracking"]);

  (function() {
    var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http") + "://my.piwik.hostname/";
    _paq.push(["setTrackerUrl", u+"piwik.php"]);
    _paq.push(["setSiteId", "2"]);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement("script"), s=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; g.type="text/javascript";
    g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+"piwik.js"; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
</script>
```

Unfortunately, looking at the webserver logs of the Piwik server, I do not receive any request. Can someone see something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is a really old question some possible answers to this:

- Do you have an AdBlocker? Disable it to enable tracking.
- Do you have DoNotTrack activated? Disable it as this can disable the tracking with Matomo.

For the first point: AdBlocker most likely filter out the scripts needed for matomo/piwik. There is nothing that you can do here.

For the second: By default the DoNotTrack is honored by matomo/piwik. You can change this setting in matomo but please respect your users choice not to be tracked.